# Nested rows in a row

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have got 3 columns (columns: FirstName, LastName, Tel )
For the FirstName and LastName I use GridBoundColumn this is fine. But for the last one I don't know what to use (I could have several numbers and there for I need several Rows in a Row). How can I solve this problem my DataSource is a List (string FirtsName, string Lastname, List Tel)

[alt text http://www.imagefilez.com/out.php/i343457_help.jpg](http://www.imagefilez.com/out.php/i343457_help.jpg)

Comment: If you want to be able to select which telephone number to use, you could use a DropDownList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a templatecolumn and in the itemtemplate add another nested list control.  Set its datasource property to your telephone list.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx) explains this approach in detail.

You can ignore the example code about RowFiltering in the RowDataBound event and just set the datasource to your list.

Comment: +1 correct - to set the datasource just do: DataSource=<%# Eval("Tel") %>